# How to get hours and minutes from UTC string?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to convert a date time from local time to UTC and later decode that UTC time back to my original local time.

To convert local time to UTC I have used below code which works fine.

```
const now = new Date();    
let d = Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 13, 5, 0);
console.log(new Date(d).getHours(), new Date(d).getMinutes());
```

The above code provides the UTC time which is +5:30 and the output is 18,35 (18:35:00)

Here, to convert back 18,35 (18:35:00) to 13:05:00 I have used below code

```
const now = new Date();
let d = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 18, 35, 0);
console.log(d.toUTCString());
```

The above code provides me a string format date which have time 13:05:00 which is proper.

Now, I want to get hours and minutes from this string of date.

I have tried adding:

```
new Date(d.UTCString())
```

But, it provides me the 18 as hours and 35 as minutes where I want 13 as hours and 05 as minutes.
Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Try this code -> console.log(d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes());

Comment: UTC is not a format.

Answer (score 5):

```js
const now = new Date();
let d = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 18, 35, 0);
console.log(d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes());
```

Comment: What is the purpose of *d*? You could just do `now.setHours(18, 35, 0)` and use *now* in the console.log part.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be way over complicating things. To get the UTC time, just use *getUTC* methods to get the hour and minute values.

To get the equivalent local time for a UTC time, use the *setUTC* methods to set the hour and minute values, e.g.

```js
// Helper to pad single digits
function z(n) {
  return ('0' + n).slice(-2);
}

let d = new Date();
let localTime = z(d.getHours()) + ':' + z(d.getMinutes());
let utcTime = z(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + z(d.getUTCMinutes());

// Print local time for d
console.log('Local time: ' + localTime);

// Print UTC time for d
console.log('UTC time: ' + utcTime);

// Set the time using UTC time in HH:mm format
utcTime = "13:05";
let [utcH, utcM] = utcTime.split(':');
d.setUTCHours(utcH, utcM);

console.log('At UTC ' + utcTime + ' the local time is ' + z(d.getHours()) + ':' + z(d.getMinutes()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Set the hours and minutes using the `setHours()` and `setMinutes()` JS date functions
2. Get the hours and minutes using the `getHours()` and `getMintues()` JS date functions

Note: The now date is based on the users current time.

```js
const now = new Date();
now.setHours(15);
now.setMinutes(30);

console.log(now.toString());
console.log(now.getMinutes());
console.log(now.getMinutes());
```

A resource for understanding the time a little more: [digtialocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-date-and-time-in-javascript)

Comment: My question is how to get time and minutes from UTC string which I get from d.toUTCString() method, If I use new Date() it will convert back to the original hours and minutes which i passed to convert

Answer (score 1):

Here is [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) method

```js
const now = new Date();    
let d = Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 13, 5, 0);

console.log('locale', new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString('ru-kz', { timeStyle: 'short' }))
console.log('utc', new Date(d).getUTCHours() + ':' + new Date(d).getUTCMinutes())
```

Comment: he wants 13 as hours and 05 as minutes

Comment: @Avi is that ok now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) . Here is a sample of getting current UTC hour and minute

```js
var curLocalDate = new Date();
var curlLocalMiliSec = curLocalDate.getTime();
var utcOffsetInMin   = curLocalDate.getTimezoneOffset();
var utcOffsetInMiliSec = utcOffsetInMin * 60 * 1000;

var utcTime = new Date(curlLocalMiliSec + utcOffsetInMiliSec);

var utcHour = utcTime.getHours();
var utcMinutes = utcTime.getMinutes();

console.log("Local time:" + curLocalDate.getHours() + ":" + curLocalDate.getMinutes());

console.log("UTC time:" + utcHour + ":" + utcMinutes);
```

Comment: Do don't need all that cruft, *getUTCHours*, *getUTCMInutes*, etc. provide the UTC equivalents directly. Shifting by the offset may move the date over a daylight saving boundary so the time may be wrong at apparently random and rare circumstances.

Comment: @RobG, as already you can find in getTimezoneOffset document: "The time zone offset returned is the one that applies for the Date that it's called on. Where the host system is configured for daylight saving, the offset will change depending on the date and time that the Date represents and that daylight saving applies.", it takes care of  daylight saving.

Comment: But in the case I described you don't want it to take care of it for you. Say you're at UTC +6 so subtract 6 hours. But that shifts you into daylight saving where the offset is +7 so only 5 hours are actually subtracted from the local time.